# Restoring database according to Postgres Guide

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I am trying to follow the Postgres [Guide](http://postgresguide.com/setup/example.html), however I think there are some issues with the following restore command.

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost example.dump
```

**It's missing a target database isn't it?**

However running the following command introduces a lot of errors,

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d pgguide example.dump
```

Even though the command above works, I think that the data restored is incomplete. I realised that in my `User` schema, I can't see any `first_name` or `last_name` as shown in the Postgres [Guide](http://postgresguide.com/sql/select.html).

Comment: What was the **exact** command to _create_ the dump? The first one works because `pg_restore` (and all other Postgres command line programs) connect to a database that is named like the current OS user if you don't specify one.

Comment: Are you running the command `pg_restore` as `postgres` user? Can you run `pg_restore -l example.dump | head -n 20`?